# Chaining LED drivers

Tags: led, shift-register

I am using the [TLC5917](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/tlc5917.pdf) to [drive LEDs](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/Foundations/ShiftOut). This is a constant current driver.

To set the current, you need to supply a resistor to ground on the R-EXT pin.

This works just fine.

The thing is, I am chaining the drivers, connecting the SDO pin to the SDI pin of the next driver.

This works when I supply every driver with its own resistor to ground, on R-EXT, as below.

[image]

I thought I could cut down on components, by using one resistor, and share that for all drivers. So all R-EXT pins connected, hooked up to a single resistor that goes to GND.

But if I do that, the LEDs of the downstream driver will not turn on?

Why can't the drivers share the R-EXT line?

Comment: Can you show how you've connected all the \$ R_{ext} \$ pins? It's not clear from your text.

Comment: I would think that having a separate resistor for each chip would be much easier to layout than having this new line that has to be routed from chip to chip.  And at 1.6 cents apiece, you're not breaking the bank on extra resistors.

Comment: @vir I am hand-soldering, though, and have 10 of them. Also, space is tight. But yeah, 10 resistors, it is, then.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Inside each TLC5917 device, and in fact, most devices that use an external resistor like that, there is a constant current source that allows the device to detect the voltage based on the external resistance and then adjust the constant current used for powering the LEDs.

When you link all of them together into one resistor, the current from all sources flows through the resistor and all kinds of things will go wrong as it is easy to exceed the expected voltages at the resistor since multiple current sources are working in parallel.

I am surprised even the first one works in that case.